# Requesting JSON response from facebook Graph API

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

This might be a very simple question, but I just need to have a JSON response from Facebook for ths query

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id='my app id'&client_secret='my secret id'&fb_exchange_token='old_token'

This works and returns a response with a long term Facebook token. But I just need to have the response in JSON format. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of the only calls in the Facebook API that does not return JSON.  You can reference the still open bug on the Facebook developers site:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/351715371565218
```

I use the FB .NET SDK and retrieve the new token thusly:

```
newAccessToken = responseString.Split('=', '&')[1];
```

Comment: What language are you using? Do you need assistance reading the response from the query?

Comment: Its just Javascript. The response is something like this

"access_token='token'&expires='expiry time'"

I was thinking of using the simple Javascript split to extract. IS there a better way to do it?

Comment: It sounds like you know how to handle it - treating the response as an array and performing a split to break apart the component parts.  I will edit my answer to show how I handle it in .NET